# Input Type as Custom Soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime

Is it possible to set the input type of a `TextView` to that of a custom IME?
I created an IME called "SimpleIME", for example I want to do something like below.

```
android:inputtype="SimpleIME"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the input type of a TextView to that of a custom IME?

No. The user gets to choose the IME, not the app developer.

Comment: is it possible to create a keyboard for a specific Activity then?

Comment: @user3424480: Not as an IME. Or, rather, you can create an IME, that you would *like* to be used by a certain activity, but nothing is stopping the user from either using that IME elsewhere or using some other IME for the activity in question.